# How to edit the contents of a jar file and repack them?

Tags: jar

I have a jar file inside which is a library that is outdated. I need to update it with the newer version and again repack the jar file to use it in my project. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The jar file is just another archive with .jar extension, so you can extract its content with any tool you use to open .zip or .rar files.

But edit class is difficult if you haven't source code . you can use https://sourceforge.net/projects/classeditor/